# How does carbon dioxide diffuse into red blood cells?

Tags: respiration, membrane-transport

> Carbon dioxide diffuses out of the tissues and into the blood, where it is dissolved in the plasma. While some of the carbon dioxide remains dissolved in the plasma, most carbon dioxide diffuses into our red blood cells. In the red blood cell, some carbon dioxide binds to hemoglobin, forming what we call carbaminohemoglobin.

Do any other gases also diffuse into the red blood cells. If not, why does only carbon dioxide get into the red blood cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The red cell membrane is highly permeable to gases because the molecules of gases are small, uncharged, and soluble in lipids, such as those of a bilayer.[The effect of 4,4′-diisothiocyanato-stilbene-2,2′-disulfonate on CO2 permeability of the red blood cell membrane](http://www.pnas.org/content/95/26/15815.short) Remember red blood cells are  cells like any other cells only that they have hemoglobin and no nucleus. Because they have an ordinary cell membrane, it follows that the laws of diffusion which apply in gases and other cells will also apply with gases and RBCs. Oxygen is the major gas which gets into RBCs, so is carbon monoxide and others

Comment: Hi welcome to Bio.SE, and thanks for contributing an answer! We generally like to see answers contain citations or other indication of sources of support for answers. Links, pictures, etc. also enhance posts. We're trying our hardest to be better than low-quality sites like Yahoo Answers and Quora, so any effort you can make to shift your post from looking like an "unfounded" personal opinion to a well-supported claim would garner you more upvotes and reputation on our site. Please take a moment to use the "edit" button below your post to indicate research effort and some citations. Thanks!!

Comment: @Moyo Freeman , can you just explain me the paper  in brief.

Comment: @Dhruva, the paper involves inhibiting trans-membrane transport proteins (Band III or capnophorin) in RBCs and then checking if they have an effect on the movement/transport of gases across the membrane.